# SAML: is it possible to force user to go through login process even when user has an IDP session

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0, spring-saml

In SAML, is it possible to force the user to go through idp's login process everytime even when the user has an active idp session?

To make a concrete example here:
Let's call my application "SP"
I use SSOCirecle as idp and I use POST and redirect (SP initiated).

To test, I will first login to SSOCircle to get an active idp session. Then when I try going to SP, I should be redirected to idp.

Normally, since I already have an active idp session, the idp will see "oh, you already being authenticated before, you can go directly to SP!"

But I don't want that, I want idp to force the user to enter credential everytime, maybe by either (I guess)

1. ignore active idp session
2. don't create an idp session

I want to knwo whether this is doable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the SP can send a flag `ForceAuthn` to the Idp in the AuthnRequest to require a new authentication instead of reusing an existing session.

As always with SAML2, you can't expect all Idps to support everything. Yyou have to test if your Idp supports the `ForceAuthn` flag.

Comment: Yes, SSOCircle supports the parameter ForceAuthn="true" in the AuthnRequest

Comment: Should also note that while they may honor ForceAuthn, depending on how they actually authenticate, there may not actually be user interaction (e.g. Kerberos/IWA).