# How can I ask Cognito to force re-authentication with a SAML IDP?

Tags: amazon-cognito, saml

I have Cognito setup with SAML authentication to both Google and Okta. It works great.

I have a use case where when a user wants to approve a record, they need to provide their username and password (a second time, just for the approval). Unfortunately, [this is the law](https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfcfr/CFRSearch.cfm?fr=11.100) set out by/for the FDA.

SAML has a mechanism to [send a request to force authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44786747/saml-is-it-possible-to-force-user-to-go-through-login-process-even-when-user-ha). Does anybody know how to get Cognito to send that request to the IDP?

Comment: Did you overcome this limitation? According to AWS Support, this is not supported yet. As a workaround, I use Cognito password as an electronic signing password and SAML is just for login. For this to be done, I ask new users to set a signing password the first time they have to sign a record.

Comment: No, I did not overcome this. We have users set a signing pin as well.