# Signle Sign-on : Microsoft 365 not asking to pick an account

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-active-directory, amazon-cognito, saml

I have implemented SSO for my application. I am using AWS Cognito as Service Provider and Azure AD as Identity Provider. IdP is configured through SAML in Cognito. Below is the URL generated

https://<my_custom_domain>.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?identity_provider=<IdP_Name>&redirect_uri=<Callback_url_passed_in_Cognito>&response_type=TOKEN&client_id=<Client_Id>&scope=aws.cognito.signin.user.admin%20email%20openid%20profile&state=transit

In my application, when a user tries to log in initially with their MS 365 account it asks for user credentials.

But after logout from the app, if the user attempts to log in again with a different account, it is not asking the user to enter credentials or pick up an existing account. It directly makes the app login for the previous account.

Note: If in my browser there are multiple MS 365 accounts signed-in then only my app asks for which account to use. If there is a single MS 365 account present then my app uses that one without asking the user to Sign-in with a different account.

Comment: Could you paste a snippet of what are you trying?

Comment: I can't share it as it's confidential. For simplicity, let's say I am displaying a login page with an email input field to the user. When a user enters the email and submits it, it will be redirected to Cognito URL mentioned above.

Comment: As SSO is configured, it allows user to access app without having to enter their login credentials again. Only if there are multiple MS 365 accounts signed-in then only my app asks for which account to use.

Comment: Single Sign-On allows users log in only once to access application without having to enter the login information each time.

Comment: Consider it as Social Sign-on instead of Single Sign-on. I want to enforce that user will be prompted with the "Pick an account" screen when there is a single MS 365 signed-in too

Answer (score 1):

Since you have specifically mentioned `SAML` for Cognito and Azure AD integration, this answer is based on that.

When SAML service provider (SP) initate a SAML auth request with Azure AD, it can specify `ForceAuthn` param as `true`. With that Azure AD should always prompt user to authenticate. Please refer [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-sign-on-saml-protocol#authnrequest). So that is supported in Azure AD.

But as far as I know, Cognito doesn't support to include that parameter in the  SAML `AuthnRequest`. Same concern has raised in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63159106) as well.

Even though I haven't tried, I think you should be able to use `Sign-out flow` in [Cognito SAML configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-managing-saml-idp-console.html) along with Azure AD [single sign-out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-sign-out-saml-protocol). So I believe it should sign out the user from Microsoft and should prompt for the credentials when user try to sign in again.

Comment: Yes. There is an IdP sign-out flow in Cognito but it will log out users from SAML IdP along with Amazon Cognito. It works and asks the end-user for credentials. But I don't want users to log out from IdP.

Comment: yeah that user experience is not so good. did you check [Conditional Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/overview)?

Comment: I don't know the exact steps. Can you tell me which condition we need to set to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

> **Note** that:

- SSO allows users to authenticate once and access applications without re-entering credentials.
- Single Sign-On allows users log in only once to access application without having to enter the login information each time.
- Hence, if there is only a single MS 365 account present then it doesn't ask user to pick an account.

For **sample**, I configured SSO and tried to access below endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=XXXX
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=redirecturi
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

The browser prompted to **Pick an account** when there were multiple accounts only like below:

[image]

**Alternatively**, you can make use of **`prompt=login`** in the authorize endpoint and enter the credentials to access the application. The prompt will be appear like below:

[image]

**Otherwise**, to ensure the `Pick an account` screen try creating a conditional policy which requires multi-factor MFA) or device compliance when user try to access the Application.

**Reference:**

[Single sign-on - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-sso#sso-between-different-apps)

Comment: I can't directly call MS login URL. I need to call the Cognito endpoint which is internally called MS 365 URL. How to set prompt=login inside Cognito or Azure AD?

Comment: Try this `https://<my_custom_domain>.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?identity_provider=<IdP_Name>&redirect_uri=<Callback_url_passed_in_Cognito>&response_type=TOKEN&client_id=<Client_Id>&scope=aws.cognito.signin.user.admin%20email%20openid%20profile&state=transit&prompt=login`

Comment: I tried. It's not working

Comment: So you want to enforce pick an account for SSO application?

Comment: Yes in the case of a single account also

Comment: AFAIK It's not feasible to do so as SSO is configured.